# Agregar datos a una una columna de un DataGrid C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

Buenas, tengo problema al momento de agregar un dato a una columna especifica de un datagrid en C#, Me sale un error que dice:

```
foreach (double inter in intervalo)
{     
    if(nAle >= (double)intervalo[2*i] && nAle<=(double)intervalo[2*i-1])
    {
        i += 1;
        pos = intervalo.Count;
        table.Rows[i].Cells[i] += 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿que plataforma?

Comment: Es en c# amigo.

Comment: El mismo Visual Studio le esta aclarando el error "System.Data.DataRow no contiene una definición de 'Cells'", utilice el valor de row para buscar la columna, le coloco un ejemplo:                                       
        int indiceRow = 1;
        DataRow row = tabla.Rows[indiceRow];
        //Por nombre de columna
        object valorColumna1 = row["nombreColumna1"];
        //Por índice de columna
        int indiceColumna = 2;
        object valorEjemplo2 = row[indiceColumna];

Answer (score 1):

Buenas Luis,

El error que tienes, tal y como indica el mensaje, es que la definición `Cells` no existe para `System.Data.DataRow`.

Para obtener una columna de una `Row` específica dentro de un `DataTable` tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach (double inter in intervalo)
{     
    if(nAle >= (double)intervalo[2*i] && nAle<=(double)intervalo[2*i-1])
    {
        i += 1;
        pos = intervalo.Count;
        table.Rows[i][i] += 1; //Pongo i respetando tu código, el segundo sería el índice de la columna
        break;
    }
}
```

El `table.Rows[i].Cells[i]` funciona correctamente cuando se trata de [`DataGridViewRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx), pero en las `DataRow` es diferente, te recomiendo que mires la [página oficial de Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) y te informes bien de las diferencias de cada clase.

Answer (score -1):

[`System.Data.DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z(v=vs.110).aspx) no contiene una propiedad llamada `Cells`. Lo que necesitas es acceder al indice de la fila utilizando `Rows[index]` y luego acceder la  columna de esa fila:

```
foreach (double inter in intervalo)
{     
    if(nAle >= (double)intervalo[2*i] && nAle<=(double)intervalo[2*i-1])
    {
        i += 1;
        pos = intervalo.Count;
        DataRow row = table.Rows[i];

        // row[i] retona un System.DataColumn por lo que le asignamos el valor a la columna con el indice i
        row[i] += 1 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ésta respuesta no aporta nada nuevo sobre las respuestas anteriores

Comment: @Marc no se como interpretaste mi respuesta pero aunque al parecer comienzan iguales, la forma de explicar es muy diferentes en ambas respuestas. No está mal agregar una explicación mas simple a un respuesta.